# Mercurial returning "no changes found" while there are changes!

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Why is that?

```
Mercurial Pull
--------------
INFO Pulling From: http://localhost/hg/hg/PorjectName/ ...
comparing with http://localhost/hg/hg/PorjectName/
searching for changes
no changes found
INFO Pulled From: http://localhost/hg/hg/PorjectName/
INFO To:        Project Name - /Users/myusername/Sites/projects/PorjectName
INFO: End of Mercurial Pull
```

I'm 100% sure there are changes, I can see it by browsing the repository.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you done an `hg update` after pulling? As this will update the working directory with the changes that were pulled from the repository.

Also, look at your local repository to see what changesets are on your local repository.

Comment: I'm guessing Will has the answer here.  Compare the output of 'hg id' and 'hg tip'.  If they differ you've pulled changes to which you've not updated.  If you're on a current-ish version of mercurial you can do 'hg summary'.

Answer (score 0):

After I cloned an empty repository, it saw all the files i already had weren't changed so i couldn't push them. I had to use my IDE's refresh file statuses

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/refreshing-status.html

which basically tells it all the files have been changes and pushes them all

I would only do this on a new repository though.